# Feedback button clarity

Tags: user-feedback, natural-language, floating-action-button

I'm currently involved in the testing of a mobile only app. In the apps product detail page there is a full width button titled, "Problem with your product?". This button is not intended to be strictly an opportunity for customers to provide feedback on the product's flaws, but to provide feedback in general.

Because of this I've started to try find a new way of saying, "Feedback" that lets the user know it can be for both positives and negatives. Below are a few top choices among my list. I would love your thoughts on which communicate this best while we are awaiting initial testing to return. Please feel free to offer your own suggestions too.

- Provide feedback
- Not what you expected?
- Question about your order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the options you provided, "provide feedback" seems like the only appropriate one since the other two are too specific and don't seem like opportunities to provide positive feedback.

I would phrase it as "Have something to tell us?". This is generic and would be recognized as an opportunity to ask about a problem, complain about the experience, or praise the experience. Additionally, answering this is an effortless question for a user to answer and might do a better job of hooking the user into the feedback flow. If the user encountered a bug, had a difficult time, or found the experience particularly painless, then they've already decided internally that they have something to communicate. The question, "have something to tell us?" has already been answered by them before they even read it and entering the feedback flow is as simple as clicking a button which reflects what they're already thinking. "Provide feedback" requires the user to stop and think: "is this going to be one of those annoying feedback surveys that websites always have and is what I want to communicate worth risking that it might be?".

A better answer would cite A/B testing results on the wording that produces the most feedback. This answer is just my opinion

Comment: Depending on space, "_Something to say?_" could be another option.